# how to implement interface property?

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

Below is my interface:

```
public interface IBaseService
{
    List<ExceptionPairs> Exceptions { get; set; }
}
```

Another interface is inheriting it:

```
public interface IClassStudentsService: IBaseService
{

}
```

I have implemented this interface in below class:

```
public class CSService : IClassStudentsService
{
    public List<ExceptionPairs> Exceptions
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

I have created a object of CSService and tried to access List `'Exceptions'` but receiving error `" Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` "

Can you please guide what I need to do instantiate it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Exceptions` is an auto-property for an object, and as such it has not been initialized before you are accessing it.

In the constructor, initialize the property with a new list:

```
public class CSService : IClassStudentsService
{
    public CSService() {
         Exceptions = new List<ExceptionPairs>();
    }

    public List<ExceptionPairs> Exceptions { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a constructor for your `CSService` class:

```
public CSService()
{
    Exceptions = new List<ExceptionPairs>();
}
```

In the constructor, you initialize the list.